# Firewall on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, firewall, virtualization

I believe I have researched my question and have not found a answer.

I have installed Virtual Box on top of Windows 10x64 and then installed three different virtual operating systems; Windows 7, Windows Server 12R2 and Ubuntu. I have a router with basic firewall abilities, which is turned on and tuned to my environment.

But I am looking to make sure, my virtual environment has a layer of security as well. If I where to install a virtual firewall in virtual box, such as OPNsense.

Do I need to add OPSense virtual firewall to each OS installation?

Link to OPNSense: https://linoxide.com/firewall/install-opnsense-virtualbox

Thanks

Comment: If you configured virtual NIC with NAT, then all the traffic goes through host Windows 10. So Windows firewall of host OS will do the work.

Comment: Thank you Biswa. 
Yes, I set up my virtual environment to pull traffic from the host Windows 10 machine. What I am hearing you say is that because i set up my virtual environment to pull traffic through the host Windows 10 machine, that I should not add a virtual firewall into Virtual box?

Comment: I'm not expert about that. But I only know some ideas/tweaks. You should ask an expert one :(

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Virtualbox network configuration.

If you use NAT, all virtual machines will connect to internet through Windows 10 x64, they will use your computer's internet and they cannot access to the router. But if you use Bridge Mode, all of them will access to the router, and they will connect to internet through the router.

I advise you to protect computer's internet connection and then share it with the virtual machines with NAT option.

To protect your computer's internet connection, you can use Opsense:
Opsense requires two network interface cards(nic). First nic is for wan connection, the second is for lan connection.

So I assume you have one Nic, you need the second nic. So install "Microsoft Loopback Adapter"

When creating Opsense, use two nics with Bridge Mode. One is for incoming connections. The other is for ongoing connections. Opsense will take incoming connections and then checks the content. And we will get internet connection from it.

1.First Network adapter: Select your own adapter. It will connect to the router directly in Bridge Mode.
2.Second Network Adapter: Select Microsoft Loopback adapter. It will give us internet connection from Opsense.

After installing Opsense, set a fixed ip for your PC at DHCP settings in Opsense WEB GUI.

Finally, your computer will use internet connections from two nics. So you need to cut internet connection of your  own network adapter. We want to use only the internet connection from Microsoft Loopback adapter.

So right click your nic. Disable IPv6. Enter the fixed ip settings of Opsense into IPv4 settings. Leave blank "dns gateway" setting. Now you are ready.

You can get detailed information at https://web.archive.org/web/20190624054042/http://timita.org/wordpress/2011/07/29/protect-your-windows-laptop-with-pfsense-and-virtualbox-part-1-preamble/

Comment: This isn't correct or at least worded poorly: The default NAT connection does _not_ deny the virtual machine access to anything. It can access the router and any other device on the local network. I also do not think OP was looking for a way to create a VM that would firewall the host system.